# how to set list of dictionaries , updating just one part

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I want to set this list of dictionaries:

```
x = [ {'a': 100, 'n':300}, {'a': 10, 'n':30}, {'a': 160, 'n':300}, {'a': 94, 'n': 346}]
```

such that:
when I update: `x[3]['n'] = 4034`

I actually want to do it like this

```
x = [ ...x, x[3]['n']=4034]
```

to get:

```
   x = [ {'a': 100, 'n':300}, {'a': 10, 'n':30}, {'a': 160, 'n':300}, {'a': 94, 'n': 4034}]
```

this is because of ReactJS useState:
 Im using it in reactJs and want to do it achieving useState, where `const [x, setx] = useState(the list of dictionaries)`, so when I call `setx(x => x = [...x, updated_part]`

Comment: is that a valid syntax?

Comment: I m thinking of updating  a list of dictionaries in place and then set it to its new value,  including the initial elements unattended and updating the new ones

Comment: Why not just `x[3]['n'] = 4034`?

Comment: i know but Im using it in reactJs and want to do it achieving useState, where const [x, setx] = useState(the list of dictionaries), so when I call setx(x => x = [...x, updated_part]